# Angular UI Router - Prevent re-running of parent state when switching between children

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I currently have a state hierarchy in my application like so;

```
- module_base
    - page_base
        - tab_one
        - tab_two
        - tab_three
```

The `page_base` state is abstract and has a Controller that returns the record for the page (e.g. `GET /products/123`) and that is then accessible to the child tabs.

The problem I'm having is that when transitioning between the tabs above the Controller for the `page_base` state re-runs every time, meaning that the product resource is retrieved on every transition.

The menu for navigating between tabs is just a list of `<a/>`s with a `ui-sref` (e.g. `<a ui-sref=".tab_one">Tab One</a>`). I have looked into the `reload` and `notify` parameters using `ui-sref-opts` but they seem to make no difference.

How can I force the `page_base` state to only load once when on page `/products/3/*` but ensure that it will re-run when on page `products/9/*`?

Also, is it possible to have `tab_*` load once when first opened, but not reload if they are revisited?

Many thanks!

State Configuration;

```
// Page Base
.state('module_base.page_base', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{id:int}',
    views: {
        base: {
            templateUrl: 'path/to/baseTemplate.html',
            controller: 'BaseController', // Reruns whenever the child states are loaded
            controllerAs: 'baseVm'
        },
        'sidebar': {
            // Configuration for the app sidebar
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        // ACL permissions check
    }
})


// Tab one
.state('module_base.page_base.tab_one', {
    url: '/tab-one',
    views: {
        'page': {
            templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
            controller: 'TabOneController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }
})

// Tab two
.state('module_base.page_base.tab_two', {
    url: '/tab-two',
    views: {
        'page': {
            templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
            controller: 'TabTwoController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a Plunker... and focusing in on the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this actually turned out to be higher up in the state hierarchy. Between each state transition an ACL permissions check was taking place, and during this process a `$rootScope` variable was being set to `false` during the check, then updated to `true` once resolved. The main application container had a `ng-if="$root.userIsAuthorised"` which removed the entire app from the DOM, then re-added it. This caused all of the routing to re-run and in turn the controllers to re run.

In short, the fix was to use `ng-show / ng-hide` to handle hiding without removing from the DOM and the controllers ran as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i think if that is what you want then you shouldn't use separate `controller` for the child tabs. so try removing `controller` and `controllerAs` properties from the state. by doing this, the parent/child (shared) `controller` gets loaded once.

Comment: The child states each have their own state-specific logic so they need their own Controllers

Comment: what if you use angularjs `service` to hold the logic?

Comment: i can't notice what you missed, but it should work the way you wanted it, at least it should only load the controller once. but this is also an alternative way to do what you want and by using `service` you code will be much more cleaner and dry.